# Connecting irrelevant branch

Tags: git, github, merge, branch

I am working on a project for a long time. Long time ago, I created 3 branch and I unlinked master branch with other sub branchs. Now I am trying to connect it again. I searched about in web but I can not find any solution...

Is there any way to connect master to sub?

[image]

You can see a sample network diagram above :)

Comment: Have you considerer merging or rebasing to bring the older branches up to date?  I presume these old branches are in the same repository.

Comment: I tried to merge _green line_ to _black line_ (... as master) but They could not be combined because they were different history. Now, I am thinking about rebasing...

Comment: What output did you get from the merge?  If you can't merge then rebasing probably also won't work.

Comment: I usually work on the web or desktop app of github. At this time, I tried on web and I got this error _"There isn't anything to compare. master and White are entirely different commit histories."_ .

Comment: Is there any logical relation between these two branches?

Comment: Absolutely not. Both of them have different history and workflow

Comment: Git performs a merge by taking each common file and then applying two diffs, from each parent, to that file.  If there is nothing in common, then one option would be to just add the files from the other older branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of git is not to create nice graph. The purpose is just to keep software versioned.

BUT, you need a response so, ... just merge branches. They did not started together. They have not same root.

Comment: Probably, I could not combine because of this reason. Thank you for the information.